# How to Back Up & Restore Database Without Filestream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

I facing problem as mention above subject. Will it possible to take only Data backup from Filestream Database and restore that backup ?

Scenario: We are storing product image to database and database size now more than 70 GB. So it’s difficult to take daily backup for the same and also time consuming. We given BCP Backup facility but we don’t won’t to relay on the same because sometime we noticed while restoring BCP Backup some of rows missing from table. Also client or we don’t bother about Image Data, if something happen then if we just restore data backup with new filestream enable, we will upload image files again.

R&D I have Done:

1)  Method  1 :

I have Taken backup with following query which I assume that it will give me just Data only.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] 
        FILEGROUP = N'PRIMARY' TO  DISK = N'E:\SendReceiveData\Test.bak' 
        WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
        NAME = N'DBName-Full Filegroup Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

Same backup now I want to restore at some other location with following Query. (With Management Studio I can’t restore the database)

```
RESTORE DATABASE [RestoreDBName] 
  FILE = N'DBName'
  FROM  DISK = N'E:\SendReceiveData\Test.bak' 
  WITH  FILE = 1,  
  MOVE N'DBName' TO N'D:\MyDatabases\RestoreDBName.mdf',  
  MOVE N'DBName_log' TO N'D:\MyDatabases\RestoreDBName_0.ldf',  
  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

But when I am checking file groups FileStream group already created even I didn’t mention while Restore Query. Also if I want to delete filestream table it is not allowing to delete and giving me Error. If I directly try to delete FilestreamGroup then also giving me Error. I thought If am able to delete filestream table & filegroup then I can create those newly and will work with new filestream but am not able to do.

2)  Method  2 :

I backup the database as shown above. But while restore I create blank database first with Filestream and try to restore the database but that also given me error.

3)  Method  3 :

I thought that Filestream table whilch is belongs to Primary FileGroup that’s why its include filestream group. So I made temporary database where One table I created with Primary FileGroup, Image table I created with ImageData FileGroup. Then taken backup only Primary File Group and assume that Image table will not come if I restore the database. But still Image table shows me in restore database. If I see the file groups then all 4 file groups (Primary, ImageData, Log & Filestream) are available.

So could you please guide me where am wrong or it’s not possible? I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Since this question is too old to migrate, I would post it on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Statements like "given me an error" are too vague for anyone to really help. What error?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not possible, if you skip the filestream related logical files during backup , the restore operation will put the database in recovery pending mode.

The reason is because the Filestream files are backed by a table in the data partition by default. So if we restore the table as part of the backup but not the actual files, then you will end up with a table that references the files, but without the files. I have tried many different ways, but i have only witnessed that the integrity do data and metadata will be lost. The only way is to have two separate databases, one for data and the other for filestreams.